# Problem with laravel-sail and composer.json

Tags: laravel, laravel-sail

I am trying to install laravel sail to an existing project that has been cloned using git

it keeps saying " Composer could not find a composer.json file in /var/www/html
To initialize a project, please create a composer.json file as described in the https://getcomposer.org/ "Getting Started" section
"

although composer.json exists in the repo

```
docker run --rm \
    -u "$(id -u):$(id -g)" \
    -v $(pwd)://var/www/html \
    -w //var/www/html \
    laravelsail/php74-composer:latest \
    composer install --ignore-platform-reqs
```

Answer (score 0):

The `docker run...` command should be run from the same directory where the project is cloned.